# How to get BufferedInputStream from Multipart?

Tags: java, multipart, bufferedinputstream

I'm trying to get a BufferedInputStream from an uploaded cvs file.

I'm working with a Multipart derived from the cvs file.

When I first get the Multipart, it's a BufferedInputStream, but the buffer is all null.

[image: Sorry. Potato Quality]

But if I look deeper down, there's another buffer in the CoyoteInputStream and that has data.

[image: Another Potato, but we're saving money by using XP's Paint]

How can I get at this second buffer? My code is below.

And of course it's throwing a null exception when it gets to

> while ((multiPartDataPos = stream.read(buffer)) >= 0)

What am I doing wrong? Am I mistaken that the CoyoteInputStream is the data I want?

public byte[] handleUploadedFile(Multipart multiPart) throws EOFException {

```
    Multipart multiPartData = null;
    BufferedInputStream stream = null;

    int basicBufferSize = 0x2000;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[basicBufferSize];

    int bufferPos = 0;

    try {

        while (multiPart.hasNext()) {

            int multiPartDataPos = bufferPos;

            multiPartData = (Multipart) multiPart.next();

            stream = new BufferedInputStream(multiPartData.getInputStream());

            while ((multiPartDataPos = stream.read(buffer)) >= 0) {

                int len = stream.read(buffer, multiPartDataPos, buffer.length - multiPartDataPos);
                multiPartDataPos += len;
            }

            bufferPos = bufferPos + multiPartDataPos;
        }

    } ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make any sense.

```
while ((multiPartDataPos = stream.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
```

At this point you have read `multiPartDataPos` bytes into `buffer`, so that `buffer[0..multiPartDataPos-1]` contains the data just read.

```
    int len = stream.read(buffer, multiPartDataPos, buffer.length - multiPartDataPos);
```

At this point you are doing another read, which could return -1, which will otherwise add some data from `multiPartPos` to `multiPartDataPos+len-`.

```
    multiPartDataPos += len;
```

This step is only valid if `len > 0`.

And you are doing nothing with the buffer; and next time around the loop you will clobber whatever you just read.

The correct way to read any stream in Java is as follows:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    // use buffer[9..count-1], for example out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

I don't understand why you think access to an underlying stream is required or what it's going to give you that you don't already have.

Comment: Thanks @EJP

I hope I can give this a try later today.

Comment: I tried your method, but I kept getting an empty BufferedInputStream. I tried using a regular InputStream and was more successful. Though I believe using a BufferedInputStream would be more efficient.

Comment: Define 'empty `BufferedInputStream`'. Reading an `InputStream` via a `BufferedInputStream` should be identical to reading the `InputStream` direct apart from the amount of data you get at a time. Unless you're misusing `available(),` of course.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the better solution was to use move the data from an InputStream to a ByteArrayOutputStream and then return  ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()

```
Multipart multiPartData = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int read;
byte[] input = new byte[4096];
InputStream is;

try {
    multiPartData = (Multipart)multipart.next();
    is = multiPartData.getInputStream();
    while ((read = is.read(input, 0, input.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(input, 0, read);
    }

    buffer.flush();
    return buffer.toByteArray(); // just a test right now
}
```